# ReactJs with Database

Tags: sql, node.js, database, reactjs, create-react-app

I need to write a term paper on databases and I want to use ReactJs to make front side. Which is the easiest way to link them. For the server I want to use nodeJs. 
Are there any examples or articles of this kind?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database?

Look into expressJS (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html)